# chosen dropdown change function not trigger in nested gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-chosen

I have a nested gridview.  When the data row in this nested grid is in edit mode, I would like to have 2 of the columns change to chosen dropdown lists. 
When the user makes a selection in the 1st dropdown, the list in the 2nd dropdown changes.  This is done on the client side using jquery.  This design works well in another grid in the application this is NOT a nested grid.

The problem is that first the dropdowns are created but are not displayed as chosen style dropdowns.  Then when the user changes the value in the 1st dropdown, the change event is not triggered and the 2nd dropdown list is not updated.  However, if you select a value in the 2nd dropdown, both controls change to the chosen style.

This is my markup:

```
<div id="RecipientWrapper">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="recipientScriptMgr" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:GridView ID="RecipientInfoGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Recipient Information" CaptionAlign="Top" 
CssClass="grid" HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="True" 
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecipientID" 
onpageindexchanging="RecipientInfoGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
onrowcancelingedit="RecipientInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
onrowcommand="RecipientInfoGridView_RowCommand" 
onrowdeleting="RecipientInfoGridView_RowDeleting" 
onrowediting="RecipientInfoGridView_RowEditing" 
onrowupdating="RecipientInfoGridView_RowUpdating"
OnRowDataBound="RecipientInfoGridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="javascript:DivExpandCollapse('div<%# Eval("RecipientID")%>');">
                <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("RecipientID")%>" alt="" width="25px" border="0" src="Images/plus.png" />
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RecipientID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="rigvLblRecipientID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="rigvLblUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="rigvTxtBxUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rigvRequiredFieldEditUserID" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxUserID" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="EditRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  ID="rigvMaxValEditUserID" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxUserID" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 40." ValidationGroup="EditRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
                CssClass="message-error" ValidationExpression="^.{1,40}$">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="rigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rigvRequiredFieldInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rigvMaxValInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 40." ValidationGroup="InsertRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                ValidationExpression="^.{1,40}$" >
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="rigvLblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientName") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="rigvTxtBxName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientName") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rigvRequiredFieldEditName" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxName" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="EditRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
                CssClass="message-error">
             </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  ID="rigvMaxValEditName" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxName" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 80." ValidationGroup="EditRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
                CssClass="message-error" ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$">
             </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="rigvTxtBxInsertName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientName") %>' ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rigvRequiredFieldInsertName" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxInsertName" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rigvMaxValInsertName" ControlToValidate="rigvTxtBxInsertName" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="InsertRecipientValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                    ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="rigvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="rigvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Recipient Information?')" >
                </asp:Button>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlDeviceNestedGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="div<%# Eval("RecipientID") %>" style="display:none">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="RecipientDeviceGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true" Caption="Device Information" 
                                        CaptionAlign="Top" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                         onpageindexchanging="RecipientDeviceGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                                         OnPageIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_PageIndexChanged" 
                                         onrowcommand="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowCommand" 
                                         onrowediting="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowEditing"
                                         onrowupdating="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowUpdating"
                                         OnRowCancelingEdit="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                                         OnRowDeleting="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowDeleting"
                                         OnRowDataBound="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowDataBound">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeviceID">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Device"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                        data-placeholder="Choose device…" class="chosen-single">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameEdit" runat="server"  
                                                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                        data-placeholder="Choose device..." class="chosen-single">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                                                        ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                                                        ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Provider">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblServiceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditServiceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_EditServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
                                                        data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameEdit" runat="server" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"
                                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_EditServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
                                                        data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditAddressExt" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceExtension") %>' 
                                                            ClientIDMode="Static">
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressEdit" runat="server" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressEdit" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" CssClass="message-error" 
                                                        ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressEdit" EnableClientScript="true" 
                                                        ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation">
                                                    </asp:CustomValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvAddressExtInsert" runat="server" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressInsert" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                                ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressInsert" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" CssClass="message-error" 
                            ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressInsert" EnableClientScript="true" 
                            ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation">
                        </asp:CustomValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActive" runat="server"  Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                                                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActiveInsert" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cortext Enabled">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblCortextEnabled" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("CortextEnabled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="recdevgvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Edit" 
                                    Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="EditDeviceValidation"></asp:Button>
                        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="recdevgvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                                    Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Device Information?')" >
                                                    </asp:Button>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="recdevgvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" CommandName="Update" 
                                        Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="recdevgvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                        Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="recdevgvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Device" CausesValidation="true" 
                                    CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation"></asp:Button>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                    <%--  <asp:HiddenField ID="recdevgvIsExpanded" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>--%>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="rigvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="EditRecipientValidation" CommandName="Update" 
                Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="rigvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="rigvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Recipient" Width="90%" CausesValidation="true" 
                CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="InsertRecipientValidation">
                </asp:Button>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //Configure the DropDownBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
    $(".chosen-single").chosen({
        search_contains: true,
        width: "200px",
        no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
    });

    //Set the Service Name values when in Edit Mode
    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").each(function () {
        alert('document ready fn: in servicename each fn');
        var DeviceSelValue = $("#recdevgvDDListDeviceName").val();
        $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").children("option").hide();
        $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");

        switch (DeviceSelValue) {
            case "1":
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='cell']").show();
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                break;
            case "2":
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='email']").show();
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                break;
            case "3":
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='page']").show();
                $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    //This change function is when the Device grid is in Edit Mode

$("#recdevgvDDListDeviceName").change(function () {
            alert('Edit Mode: Device name DDL change fn');
            $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").val('');
            $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").chosen({
                search_contains: true,
                no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
            });
            $("#recdevgvTxtBoxAddress").val('');

            var DeviceSelValue = $(this).val();
            $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").children("option").hide();
            $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");

            switch (DeviceSelValue) {
                case "1":
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='cell']").show();
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvEditAddressExt").hide();
                    //       $("#recdevgvTxtBoxAddress").width("50%");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='email']").show();
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvEditAddressExt").hide();
                    //     $("#recdevgvTxtBoxAddress").width("90%");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName option[value*='page']").show();
                    $("#recdevgvDDListServiceName").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvEditAddressExt").hide();
                    //      $("#recdevgvTxtBoxAddress").width("50%");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
```

Finally, this is the code behind RowEditing event that creates the dropdowns.

```
 protected void RecipientDeviceGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView tgvRecipientDevice = (GridView)sender;
        tgvRecipientDevice.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        int tiRecipientID = Convert.ToInt32((tgvRecipientDevice.Parent.FindControl("rigvLblRecipientID") as Label).Text);
        populateDeviceGrid(tgvRecipientDevice, tiRecipientID);

        string tstrXmlTableData = string.Empty;
     //   Get the current Device Name
        string tstrCurrentDevice = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvEditDeviceName") as Label).Text;

        DropDownList tddLstDeviceName = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvDDListDeviceName") as DropDownList);
        tstrXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetDeviceTypes();
        DataTable tdtDeviceTypes = CommonMethods.ParseXML(tstrXmlTableData);
        tddLstDeviceName.DataSource = tdtDeviceTypes;
        tddLstDeviceName.DataTextField = tdtDeviceTypes.Columns["DeviceName"].ToString();
        tddLstDeviceName.DataValueField = tdtDeviceTypes.Columns["DeviceTypeID"].ToString();
        tddLstDeviceName.DataBind();
        tddLstDeviceName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
        tddLstDeviceName.Items.FindByText(tstrCurrentDevice).Selected = true;

        //Get the current Service Provider
        string tstrCurrentService = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvEditServiceName") as Label).Text;

        DropDownList tddLstServiceName = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvDDListServiceName") as DropDownList);
        tstrXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetServiceTypes();
        DataTable tdtServiceTypes = CommonMethods.ParseXML(tstrXmlTableData);
        tddLstServiceName.DataSource = tdtServiceTypes;
        tddLstServiceName.DataTextField = tdtServiceTypes.Columns["ServiceName"].ToString();
        tddLstServiceName.DataValueField = tdtServiceTypes.Columns["CombineID_Group"].ToString();
        tddLstServiceName.DataBind();
        tddLstServiceName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
        tddLstServiceName.Items.FindByText(tstrCurrentService).Selected = true;

        Label tlblEditAddressExt = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvEditAddressExt") as Label);
        TextBox ttxtBoxAddress = (tgvRecipientDevice.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("recdevgvTxtBoxAddress") as TextBox);
        if ((tstrCurrentService.Equals("SMTP")) || (tstrCurrentService.Equals("Other")))
        {
            tlblEditAddressExt.Visible = false;
            tlblEditAddressExt.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            tlblEditAddressExt.Visible = true;
            //Parse the string in the text field to only have the cell phone or pager number
            string tstrAddress = ttxtBoxAddress.Text;
            ttxtBoxAddress.Text = tstrAddress.Substring(0, tstrAddress.IndexOf("@"));    
        }

        ExpandChildGrid(tgvRecipientDevice, tiRecipientID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TO DO:Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
    }
}
```

So, to reiterate...the chosen style is not created when the grid is in edit mode and the jquery 'change' event is not triggered by the DeviceName dropdown.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I figured out part of my problem...the dropdown for the DeviceName did not have the attribute `Autopostback=true`. That got the document ready function to fire and update the ServiceName dropdown.

However, now when the DeviceName dropdown is changed, it closes the nested gridview.  After the change, the grid needs to remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the chosen plugin was not triggered was due to the UpdatePanel replaces the contents of the panel.  All of the events need to be re-subscribed to. This is done using the following javascript code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onEndRequest);       
    function onEndRequest(sender, args) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            $("select:not(.chosen-select, .no-chosen)").chosen({
                search_contains: true,
                width: "200px",
                no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
            });
        }
    };
```